# Reason for using Class instead of actual type in this java example?

Tags: java, awt

I have seen this "design pattern" (don't know what else to call it.. template?) show up more than once in Java code.  Application is expected to be extended and include a main method.  I can't figure out what the benefit is of using Class instead of the AppFrame in the start method since it is just type casted to AppFrame anyways.  It just all seems so pointless, maybe somebody can fill me in.

```
public class Application {

 public static class AppPanel extends JPanel {
  //stuff
 }

 public static class AppFrame extends JFrame {
  protected AppPanel mainPanel;
  //more stuff
 }

 public static AppFrame start(Class appFrame) {
  try {

   final AppFrame frame = (AppFrame) appFrame.newInstance();
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
   return frame;
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
  Application.start(AppFrame.class);
 }
}
```

Comment: where did you find that code?

Comment: I have seen that outline more than once.  I saw the worldwind application examples use it the other day and it bothered me enough to investigate.  I have been trying to figure out why people do this for some time.

Comment: There might be a specific reason why this example does this, but it's not a standard pattern, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Someone needs to clear up the hysteria about touching GUI stuff from a non-GUI thread. I've always gone by the principle that instantiating the GUI stuff and then doing `setVisible()` from the outside is OK. If this is untrue, then an awful lot of extant code is in danger, and one is required to write amazing heaps of boilerplate.

Comment: Touching GUI stuff off the EDT does cause problems (much more apparent on multiprocessor systems, and depends what you are doing on what particular JRE implementation). Don't do it. Write the required boilerplate.

Comment: That's it, I'm dumping Java. Or at least I'm gonna sit down and pout. @Tom: Thanks!

Comment: @Carl - see http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html for (probably) the oldest article on this - there may be some cases where you are OK, but I err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen that around too, particularly in fairly old examples.

The idea seems to be that everything starts with a single static call, and the user does not create anything on the heap. Instead, the "Application framework" somehow instantiates what it needs and the user only instructs what specific implementations to use. Thus, the user indicates the class to use, but nothing is actually instantiated yet. One risk of doing this is that you could transfer a class whose instances are not convertible to an AppFrame. This can result in an exception.

I personally consider this ugly design. It makes sense in languages where it is more common to directly instantiate a class via a class object like Smalltalk or Python. In Java, I think that sticking with factory interfaces is clunkier yet more OO.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is called a `type token`, a term coined by Gilad Bracha and discussed in [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html), as well as [mentioned here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Resources/Links/JavaGenerics.htm). It is an interesting way to instantiate the top-level container, a `JFrame`, but the GUI components should be constructed on the [Event Dispatch Thread(EDT)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Depending on `//stuff` in the constructors and how `start()` is called, it may mitigate the effect of an [escaped this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618.html).

Comment: Type token is for parameterised types, for instance `ArrayList<String>` which cannot be represented by `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: In this example the gui components were constructed on the main thread, should all of that have been moved to the invokelater?  Also, what about the use of Class, it could have been instantiated on the EDT with "new" instead right?  I think im missing something.

Comment: @insipid: you are correct; I misread the code. Skaffman & tackline are also correct that the GUI must be built on the EDT, not just made visible. The tutorial gives the preferred approach.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of start() allows passing of any class, but implementation restricts it to the children of AppFrame and the latter is just a nested static class. Since everything is piled into the same file I don't why all of this is necessary and I agree - the way it is implemented in this particular example is pointless.